# Click a button with no id within an iframe on website?

Tags: vba, excel, button, iframe

I'm trying to use excel to auto populate a web form. I am able to log in and fill in some of the fields in the iframe but so far am unable to click on a button and also unable to fill in drop down lists which are in iframes. This is my code so far:

```
Sub AutoFill()
Dim ieApp As Object
Dim div As Variant

'create a new instance of ie
Set ieApp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ieApp.Visible = True

ieApp.navigate "webpage"
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

ieApp.document.all("login_email").Value = "username"
ieApp.document.all("login_password").Value = "password"
ieApp.document.all("login_button").Click

Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

Dim button As HTMLInputButtonElement
Set button = _
ieApp.document.getElementById("internal_tab_text_client_products")
button.Focus
button.Click
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

'To fill in name on the web form:
Dim HTMLdoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim htmlWindow As MSHTML.HTMLWindow2
Set HTMLdoc = ieApp.document
Set htmlWindow = HTMLdoc.frames(0)
htmlWindow.document.all("_text_5204102016102444865_FIELD").Value = _
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("a1")

Dim frame As HTMLFrameElement
Dim img
Set HTMLdoc = ieApp.document
Set frame = HTMLdoc.getElementsByName("main_content_window")(0)
Set HTMLdoc = frame.contentDocument

'Clicks a bubble on the webform
Set img = HTMLdoc.getElementById("_radioyn_227072016141926252_FIELD_NO")
img.Click

'to click the button (doesn't work):
Set img = HTMLdoc.getElementByTagName("button")
img.click
End Sub
```

When I get down to click the button in my code it has an object error. The button I am trying to Click on the website has the following code for the iframe:

```html
<iframe
  id="main_content_window" 
  style="width:100%;height:99.5%;border:none;"
  onload="resizeEmbeddedPanel();"
  scrolling="yes"
  src="....php"
>
```

And the button is slightly below it with the following code:

```html
<button
  title="Start New"
  style="
          background-color: rgb(4,61,111);
          color:rgb(255,255,255);
          width:122px;
          height:33px;
          padding-left:0px;
          padding-right:0px;
          font-size:12px;
          font-weight:bold;
        "
  onclick="toggleNewBusinessMenu(); return false;"
>
```

**EDIT:**

Got the button figured out! Now I just need help with picking from a drop down list in an iFrame. Here is the website code for the drop down:

```html
<select
  storage_var="1"
  object_id="F6F136889A5511E786D7F8BC12333350" 
  label_text="Choose+Program%3A" 
  linked_var="DM:Submission.none.policy.line_of_business" 
  context="F6F136889A5511E786D7F8BC12333350"
  data_type="Text" 
  id="F6F136889A5511E786D7F8BC12333350_droplist_127072016125151333_FIELD" 
  style="background-color:#FFFFFF;color:#000000;cursor:default;;width:100%;" 
  onselectstart="return true"
  field_data_type="Text" 
  onkeydown="top.onFieldKeyDown(event, window, 0);" 
  onkeyup="top.onFieldKeyUp(event, window, 0);" 
  onpaste="top.onFieldKeyUp(event, window, 0);"
  onblur="return 
  top.defaultBlurEvent(this, -1);"
  onchange="return window.ev_F6F136889A5511E786D7F8BC12333350_droplist_127072016125151333_action(event); "
  date_format="mm/dd/yy"
  value=""
  class=""
>
  <option value="">Please Select</option>
  <option value="HO_FLD">Home &amp; Flood</option>
  <option value="FLD">Flood Only</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "clicking" the button in the iframe and indirectly running the event handler code, you could run the *actual* event handler code directly.

The following should work:

```
htmlWindow.execScript("toggleNewBusinessMenu();", "JavaScript")
```

---

## * **IMPORTANT NOTE** *

An iframe is essentially an embedded, ***completely independent*** web page. As such, its elements are not directly accessible from the main DOM. You have to specifically create a new iframe DOM in order to access these elements. How to do this can be seen in the last code block below.

---

**EDIT:**

To actually "click" the button, you can find the button by enumerating the `button` elements like this:

```
Dim elmButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
For Each elmButton In HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("button")
  If elmButton.getAttribute("title") = "Start New" Then
    elmButton.Click
    Exit For
  End If
Next elmButton
```

Note that the `.getElementsByTagName()` method returns a *collection* of elements. Your code returns an error because you tried to use the non-existent `.getElementByTagName()` method (missing the `s`).

A better way to click the button would be to use the `querySelector()` method:

```
HTMLdoc.querySelector("button[title='Start New']").Click
```

---

**EDIT:**

To select a item from a drop down list use:

```
' Select "FLD" from droplist
HTMLdoc _
  .querySelector("select[id='F6F136889A5511E786D7F8BC12333350_droplist_127072016125151333_FIELD']") _
  .selectedIndex = 2
```

---

**EDIT:** (v0.1.1) Bug-fix

I've added a rewritten copy of your code, demonstrating a consistent style of accessing objects in the DOM by using  the `querySelector()` method. I've included a few comments documenting certain pitfalls when using the DOM.

```
'============================================================================================
' Module     : <in any standard module>
' Version    : 0.1.1
' Part       : 1 of 1
' References : Microsoft HTML Object Library [MSHTML]
'            : Microsoft Internet Controls   [SHDocVw]
' Source     : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46232023/1961728
'============================================================================================
  ' Required if late binding MSHTML
  Private Enum tagREADYSTATE
    READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED = 0
    READYSTATE_LOADING
    READYSTATE_LOADED
    READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE
    READYSTATE_COMPLETE
  End Enum

Public Sub AutoFill()

  ' Create and use a new instance of IE
  With New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer '##Late Binding: CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    .Visible = True ' False is default
    
    .Navigate "<webpage>"
    Do Until .Busy = False And .ReadyState = SHDocVw.tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop '##Late Binding: = tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE  ##No Enums: = 4
    
    ' Get and use the main DOM
    With .Document
      ' .all() is deprecated. Suggest you use .querySelector()
      ' In the rest of the code, change "id" to "name" or other attribute as required
      ' (Also strongly suggest you change "*" to the appropriate tag name)
      .querySelector("*[id='login_email']").Value = "username"
      .querySelector("*[id='login_password']").Value = "password"
      .querySelector("*[id='login_button']").Click
      Do Until .Busy = False And .ReadyState = SHDocVw.tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop '##Late Binding: = tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE  ##No Enums: = 4
      
      .querySelector("*[id='internal_tab_text_client_products']").Click
      Do Until .Busy = False And .ReadyState = SHDocVw.tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop '##Late Binding: = tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE  ##No Enums: = 4
    
      ' Get and use the iframe's DOM
      Dim domIFrame As MSHTML.HTMLDocument '##Late Binding: As Object
      Set domIFrame = .frames("main_content_window").Document ' Could use querySelector here too, but that requires 3 lines instead of 1
      ' domIFrame is required - using With .frames(0).Document -> Run-time error '438'@ .querySelector(…)
      With domIFrame
        ' Fill in name on the web form:
        .querySelector("*[id='_text_5204102016102444865_FIELD']").Value _
        = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Value2
        
        ' Click a radio button on the web form:
        .querySelector("*[id='_radioyn_227072016141926252_FIELD_NO']").Click
        
        ' Select "FLD" from droplist
        .querySelector("select[id='F6F136889A5511E786D7F8BC12333350_droplist_127072016125151333_FIELD']") _
          .selectedIndex = 2
        ' 0 = <option value="">Please Select</option>
        ' 1 = <option value="HO_FLD">Home &amp; Flood</option>
        ' 2 = <option value="FLD">Flood Only</option>
        
        ' Click the "Start New" button:
        .querySelector("button[title='Start New']").Click
      End With
    End With
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Okay thank you, however when I put this into my code it says "=" is expected. Is there something else I should have in there?

Comment: @KristinaS I don't think so. (You could try using `"toggleNewBusinessMenu(); return false;"` instead, but I don't expect it to make a difference.) Is the site one where I could easily get an account for? It would be easier if I could try out the code myself.

Comment: @KristinaS I've updated the answer with the other way to "click" the button.

Comment: I have actually tried your edited version before, it doesn't work because it cant find the button because it is located in an iFrame. I also tried your first option but it still says "=" is expected. Not sure if I'm missing something. I would give you the web address but its a secure website for my work. I could add more code if that would help?

Comment: Never mind got it to work!! I used:     htmlWindow.execScript ("toggleNewBusinessMenu();") Thank you for the help!!

Comment: @KristinaS Damn! The usual missing semi-colon. I'll update the answer.  As far as the second method is concerned, as long as you've set `HTMLdoc` correctly to the frame's document (which it *looks* like you have done) enumerating the `button` elements ***will*** work. PS Don't forget to Accept/Up Vote answers to you questions appropriately.

Comment: Thanks again! I tried Up voting your answer but won't let me :(. I edited my post to reflect the drop down problem now. Would you know how to code this? I tried using htmlWindow.document.all("ID").Value="FLD" but this runs an error. Not sure why this doesn't work.

Comment: @KristinaS re up voting and accepting (clicking the "tick"), you need to enable javascript, specifically for `sstatic.net`, `ajax.googleapis.com`, and  `stackoverflow.com`. For the drop down list, hopefully `HTMLdoc.getElementById("_radioyn_227072016141926252_FIELD_NO").setAttribute "value", "FLD"` should work. Off to bed now. If you haven't solved it by then, I'll have a look at it when I get up.

Comment: So I tried what you suggested and it says "Object variable not set". I'll keep trying though. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @KristinaS Sorry. Just realized I forgot to post the correct drop down list code. (The one in the comment uses the wrong id and the wrong method. I *was* very tired ;) ) I've updated the answer with the working code. I've also added some more information and a rewritten copy of your entire code for your perusal.

Comment: Wow thank you! There is one problem I'm encountering though. When I try to use Set domIFrame = .frames("main_content_window").Document, it always runs an error. That's why I didn't use this in my original code. Do you know why this would be?

Comment: I tried just inputting the querySelector into my code and it still runs an error. It seems like it can't find the drop down.

Comment: Just figured out that its not recognizing the code once I reach <div style= "overflow:hidden;"> which is where the drop down list is embedded.

Comment: @KristinaS Oops! Hard to check the code without a live site to work with. I've updated the answer with a bug-fix. (The `.frames()` was running against the IE object instead of the DOM object). The fix *should* work. If it doesn't, could you add the full iframe html to the end of your question and then ping me?